# How to put comments before comment box using disqus comment system

Tags: css, layout, comments, disqus

I'm using the Disqus comment system for my site and I found that comment box is on top, before the comments. How can I put the comment box *after* the comments?

I've already tried logging in to Disqus and looking in Admin > Settings > Appearance and found that the Narcissus theme has a layout just like what I need, but even after I activate it, my site still shows the comments after the comment form.

I also sent an email to Disqus, but they haven't replied to me.

So, any idea how to do it using CSS, or any other method?

Answer (score 0):

Have you set 'Comment Form Position' to 'Bottom of Thread'?

You can find these options below the theme selector in the Appearance tab